# Deciding whether the cofinite topology is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Given an arbitrary set $X$, we define a topology
$$ 
\mathcal{T} = \{S \subset X \mid \# (X - S) < \infty \text{ or } S = \emptyset\}. 
$$
I'm trying to decide whether $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is metrizable.

A hint I was given was to split into cases of whether $X$ is finite or infinite. So I'll suppose first that $X$ is finite. Then for every $S$, $X - S$ is finite, so every $S$ is open. That corresponds to the discrete topology, or the topology induced by the discrete metric. So it seems to be metrizable in this case.

Not every complement is finite in the case where $X$ is infinite. I don't have a good strategy in mind for describing the open sets so I'm not sure how to proceed, but it seems much tougher to describe a metric.

I would appreciate a hint on how to proceed. I'm very stuck on how to think about this problem from the ground up, so I would be very interested in some intuition for how to approach a problem asking whether $(X, \mathcal{T})$ for some topology is metrizable. Do I run through all of the metrics that I've seen so far? Even then, that would depend on the open sets. I have the discrete metric on any set, several metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a product metric, and a few more. None of them seem applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is metrisable, it must have all the topological properties that *every* metric space has.

It's easy to see that

- all metric spaces (in their metric topology of course) are Hausdorff, regular,normal, completely normal and perfectly normal.
- all metric spaces are first countable.
- if a metric space is separable (i.e. has a countable dense subset) it also has a countable base for its topology.
- if a metric space is countably compact, it is also compact.

These are all properties that general spaces can fail to have, and in that case we are sure that there cannot be any metric that induces its topology. It's like we know "all ravens are black", so if we see a green bird, it cannot be a raven.

Most proofs of a space being non-metrisable come down to finding some property that all metrisable spaces have but the space at hand does not.
To see that a topology *is* metrisable is easiest by actually defining a metric for it and proving it works. Which is what you did for the finite case, because it's a well-known fact that the discrete metric $d(x,y)=\delta_x(y)$ induces the discrete topology. That's often the easy case and at least concrete. The refuting part requires you to search properties like I listed.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is not a finite set but has the cofinite topology, then two non-empty open sets can't be disjoint, so the topology isn't Hausdorff.